# Setting init_connect to a string with spaces in an Amazon RDS Parameter Group using the command line interface complains with malformed errors

Tags: bash, amazon-rds

I'm trying to set the init_connect parameter to "SET NAMES utf8"

```
rds-modify-db-parameter-group mygroup --parameters="name=init_connect, value='SET NAMES utf8', method=immediate"
```

but it fails with:

```
rds-modify-db-parameter-group:  Malformed input-No value separator = found in NAMES
```

I haven't found any examples that give a good idea how one might do this. Is it possible? Is there some way to escape it that I'm missing?

Comment: It seems you can use RDS Console to set `init_connect` to `SET NAMES utf8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have ran across the same problem in attempting to use init_connect='SET AUTOCOMMIT=0', however, there is another way for you to solve your problem and that is by using the following:

rds-modify-db-parameter-group mygroup -p "name=skip-character-set-client-handshake, value=TRUE, method=pending-reboot"

This effectively accomplishes the same thing as forcing the "set names 'utf8'" on connect.  It will ignore the client information and use the default server character set.  Of course you have to ensure that the default server character set is UTF8 (which it is not by default.)  Therefore, add the following parameters to your group as well:

rds-modify-db-parameter-group mygroup -p "name=character_set_server, value=utf8, method=immediate" -p "name=collation_server, value=utf8_general_ci, method=immediate"

Comment: Nice fix, thanks! Not sure if I should mark this solved or not, though – it doesn't quite answer the original question, it works around it. We're still not sure how to use spaces inside params. I'm going to mark it solved in this case, and if the powers that be want to over-rule that call, go for it.

Comment: awesome! this is the only way i found to change `collation_server` from `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`.